# Modified files after git svn fetch. What does it mean and how to fix that

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

We're going to use git instead of SVN and doing some research at the moment. I've tried to create git repository based on our SVN one. `git svn` is perfect. But after clone/fetch I've seen modified files in few repos (2 of 4 actually).

What is that? How to overcome that?

UPDATE: in both of repos that have modified files we could see same: files that are modified has upper case letter in name. For example: `paid.gif` and `Paid.gif` exists in SVN, and also in GIT, and `Paid.gif` becomes modified somehow. Also not only images, but other files that are named same (but differs with letter case) becomes modified.

Also svn repo is on Linux, but git is on my Mac, maybe it's important.

Comment: How are they different? Are they only line-ending differences, and have you verified that either with `git diff`, or by a standard diffing of the files in one repo against the other?

Comment: nope, diff with few lines. But what is strange: we have to files, that are named almost equivalent, e.g. `mypopup.js` and `myPopup.js`. And it shows that second file is changed, but it doesn't exist in working directory. Strange.. Look at update..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then it's easy. MacOS filenames are [case insensitive](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1037142). So content is conflicting. And it is not git fault, so either work on Linux, reformat hdd or rename files to avoid clashes. Or maybe it is possible to use another filesystem on a Mac?..

Comment: Thanks for explanation. We will rename/remove duplicate files.